# Java stream sorted() don`t work in cyrillic

Tags: java, java-stream

Sorting don't work as expect in cyrillic. I use method sorted() but it's not work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {              

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Єгипет");
    list.add("Азербайджан");
    list.add("Албанія");
    list.add("Алжир");
    list.add("Чілі");
    list.add("Швейцарія");
    list.add("Швеція");
    list.add("Шрі-Ланка");
    list.add("Японія");
    list.add("Ґуам");
    list.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Result:

```
Єгипет
Азербайджан
Албанія
Алжир
Чілі
Швейцарія
Швеція
Шрі-Ланка
Японія
Ґуам
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve alphabetical order sorting by using a `Collator` like documented in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html).

For supported `Locale`s, you can refer to the [supported ones](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html) where `ru-RU` is also documented (using `uk-UA` for Ukrainian produces the same result)

```java
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru", "RU"));

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Єгипет");
list.add("Азербайджан");
list.add("Албанія");
list.add("Алжир");
list.add("Чілі");
list.add("Швейцарія");
list.add("Швеція");
list.add("Шрі-Ланка");
list.add("Японія");
list.add("Ґуам");

list.stream().sorted(collator::compare).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Азербайджан
Албанія
Алжир
Ґуам
Єгипет
Чілі
Швейцарія
Швеція
Шрі-Ланка
Японія
```

---

Thanks to the comment of @Holger, it can even be simplified to `collator` instead of `collator::compare`

```
list.stream().sorted(collator).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: what if I have an object with with a string field I want to sort instead of string list?

Comment: in Kotlin: `localeList.sortedWith(compareBy(Collator.getInstance(locale)) { it.displayName })`

Answer (score 4):

As per the `Stream.sorted()` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sorted()), the stream is sorted according to natural order, which means it uses the `String.compareTo()` method. In turn, this uses [lexicographical order](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) - i.e. the Unicode values of each character. "Є" comes before "А" in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_(Unicode_block)). The original "А" to "Я" range was just the Russian characters. I assume you're using Ukrainian; these additional letters, such as "Є", were added outside this block.

To fix this, you should use the [sorted() method that takes a custom Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)). In your comparator, use an instance of [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) based on the appropriate Locale.

Comment: Great answer ! :)